# Работа с датами, вывод всех выходных дней за определенный месяц и год

Tags: java, дата, datetime

Не понимаю как получить из определенного месяца в опр. году список всех суббот и воскресений
Вот пример моего кода, но он в консоль выводит не правильный день недели

```
      public class TestApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1);
    int day = date.lengthOfMonth();
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    int startDay = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < day; i++) {
        LocalDate newdate = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, startDay);
        calendar.set(newdate.getYear(), newdate.getMonthValue(), startDay);
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(newdate);
        }
        startDay++;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Одновременное применение Java 8 Date/Time API `LocalDate` и давно устаревшего `GregorianCalendar` выглядит достаточно противоестественным, достаточно упомянуть, что в `Calendar/GregorianCalendar` месяцы начинаются c 0, а дни недели идут от 1 (воскресенье) до 7 (суббота). поэтому при установке месяца следует хотя бы вычесть 1 для коррекции.

Впрочем, имеет смысл полностью выбросить `GregorianCalendar`, а в качестве переменных цикла использовать экземпляр `LocalDate`:

```java
    int count = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for (LocalDate d = date; d.getMonth() == date.getMonth(); d = d.plusDays(found ? 7 : 1)) {
        if (DayOfWeek.SUNDAY == d.getDayOfWeek()) {
            count++;
            found = true;
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sundays: " + count);
```

Вывод:

```
2022-01-02
2022-01-09
2022-01-16
2022-01-23
2022-01-30
Sundays: 5
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, отметьте его зеленой галочкой :)